# Dynamic StringFormat in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following TextBlock Style:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="MyValues">
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMetric}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="F1">

                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMetric}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="F3">

                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

I then use `TextBlocks` as follows:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Breadth}" Style="{StaticResource MyValues}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Depth}" Style="{StaticResource MyValues}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Area}" Style="{StaticResource MyValues}" />
```

The intention is to set the StringFormat depending on a bound property `IsMetric`. The Binding in the style are left empty because i want to apply the same style for multiple TextBlocks all bound to different properties. The triggers are working but the StringFormat` is ignored, any ideas?

Comment: this would be a lot easier with a converter

Answer (score 2):

Here you set `Text` property to be different things in `TextBlock` declaration and in `DataTriggers`. In the first case it's an instance of `Binding` class. In the second case it's an instance of `MultiBinding` class. Finally it is one of these. It cannot be both at the moment.

The following markup

```
<Setter Property="Text">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="F1">

        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**instantiates** `MultiBinding` class instance and sets it to `Text` property.

The `Text="{Binding Path=Breadth}"` **instantiates** `Binding` class instance and sets it to `Text` property.

Comment: Makes sense! Is there a way round this?

Comment: Can't see any way around other than the one proposed by @pivotnig - using ValueConverter